# How to sort an array with respect of distance from database

Tags: php, android, sorting, listview

How to sort an array with respect of distance from database.

I am facing a problem in sorting of an array. I have places data store in database and I want to retrieve it from database to android in a list but in the form of sorted. For example I want my list sorted with distance.

I know how to do this but the major problem is this that I want only 5 min distance places then loading and in another request 5 more min distance.

For example:

In my first request I have this:

```
{
 [name:abc,distance:2km],
 [name:abc,distance:4km],
 [name:abc,distance:4.5km],
 [name:abc,distance:5.4km],
 [name:abc,distance:6km]
}
```

this data set in my listview with adapter
after this load more data and in second array i want

```
{ 
  [name:xyz,distance:7km],
  [name:abc,distance:8km],
  [name:abc,distance:9km],
  [name:abc,distance:10km],
  [name:abc,distance:11km]
}
```

How it possible and how to do this? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have the whole sorted array in the way you want. Then you return X elements of it to the user. When you want to load next places in the order, pass the number of previous listed/returned places (or pass the key of the last element returned). On the next load you will pass the number of loaded results so far and your backend will know from which element of your sorted array to start.